# Scrolling in less in a byobu pane in terminal

Tags: command-line, mouse, scrolling, byobu

When I run `less file.txt` (for example) in a terminal, I can use the mouse wheel to scroll through `file.txt`.

When running `less file.txt` in a byobu pane, one of two things happens when I scroll with the mouse wheel:

If byobu `mouse-mode` is off, the entire terminal scrolls, pushing `byobu` itself off the screen and nothing is passed to `less`.

If byobu `mouse-mode` is on, then the pane enters scrollback mode with the `[10/220]` line counter in the top corner, and nothing is passed to `less`.

How do I configure `byobu` to send mouse events through to the pane in which I am scrolling?

I am using xfce4-terminal on Xubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Found solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/989505/pass-mouse-events-through-tmux/1319237#1319237)

Comment: This should probably be marked as a duplicate, but it won't let me since the answer is on unix.SE

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/989505/pass-mouse-events-through-tmux/1319237#1319237)

```
# Emulate scrolling by sending up and down keys if these commands are running in the pane
tmux_commands_with_legacy_scroll="nano less more man git"

bind-key -T root WheelUpPane \
    if-shell -Ft= '#{?mouse_any_flag,1,#{pane_in_mode}}' \
        'send -Mt=' \
        'if-shell -t= "#{?alternate_on,true,false} || echo \"#{tmux_commands_with_legacy_scroll}\" | grep -q \"#{pane_current_command}\"" \
            "send -t= Up Up Up" "copy-mode -et="'

bind-key -T root WheelDownPane \
    if-shell -Ft = '#{?pane_in_mode,1,#{mouse_any_flag}}' \
        'send -Mt=' \
        'if-shell -t= "#{?alternate_on,true,false} || echo \"#{tmux_commands_with_legacy_scroll}\" | grep -q \"#{pane_current_command}\"" \
            "send -t= Down Down Down" "send -Mt="'
```